# Android отсчет времени

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Раньше на Java я использовал `scheduleAtFixedRate()` для отсчета времени

Появилось ли что - нибудь новое в Kotlin?

И имеется ли какой - нибудь style guide от Google по поводу компонентов, которые отсчитывают время?
В Material Design не нашел ничего

Update. Я использовал CountDownTimer, но я не могу его заставить работать, проблема в том, что я пытаюсь его запустить из потока получения данных

```
private var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null
    private fun getProfile() {
    val thread = object : Thread() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun run() {
        ......получение данных....
            Log.d("Firstt", premiumInfo.overTime.time.toString())
            Log.d("Second", System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
            countDownTimer?.cancel()
            countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(premiumInfo.overTime.time, System.currentTimeMillis()){
                override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
                    Log.d("Timer", p0.toString())
                }
                override fun onFinish() {
                    Log.d("Finish", "true")
                }
            }
        }
    }
.start()
```

Получившийся Log:

```
2020-05-13 17:03:37.069 13885-13885/com.app.peshkariki D/Firstt: 1589389486000
2020-05-13 17:03:37.069 13885-13885/com.app.peshkariki D/Second: 1589378617069
2020-05-13 17:03:37.101 13885-13885/com.app.peshkariki D/Timer: 1589389485968
```

Я подумал что это из-за того что я запускаю в потоке,

поэтому я вытащил за поток запуск

```
thread.start()
countDownTimer?.start()
```

Но как я понял, на момент того, что когда мы запустили thread, а потом переходим к нашему timer, то данные еще не успели прийти с сервера, поэтому оно равно null?

```
2020-05-13 17:12:20.462 16350-16350/com.app.peshkariki D/Firstt: 1589390006000
2020-05-13 17:12:20.462 16350-16350/com.app.peshkariki D/Second: 1589379140462
```

Подскажите с решением...

**Update2**

Кажется я понял, второе число это не время, когда заканчивается timer, а размер tick?

Comment: это `Timer`? А есть какая-то причина или недостаток в Timer, что вы ищете что-то другое?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `Timer` для прямого счета

```
val timer = Timer()
timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {

    }
}, 1000)
```

и `CountDownTimer` для обратного отсчета

```
val countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(10000 , 1000) {
    override fun onTick(millis: Long) {

    }
    override fun onFinish() {

    }
}
countDownTimer.start()
```

Comment: добавил вопрос ниже